# Sitecore Solr rebuildcore feature causes 'Could not create instance'

Tags: solr, sitecore, sitecore8

Sitecore 8.0 Update 6
Solr 5.2.1

Implementing Solr Search with Sitecore and want to use the rebuildcore option. I have two cores in Solr. I update my Solr index config with a patch file like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Purpose: This include file defines the indexes used by the content testing feature of Sitecore when using the SOLR content search provider. -->
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <contentSearch>
      <configuration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
        <indexes hint="list:AddIndex">
           <index id="sitecore_analytics_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
              <param desc="core">sitecore_frontend_index</param>
              <param desc="rebuildcore">sitecore_frontend_index_sec</param>
           </index>
       </configuration>
     </contentSearch>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

But when I browse to the site I get:

Could not create instance of type: Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex. No matching constructor was found.

Its definitely the rebuildcore parameter because removing it and switching it back to SolrSearchIndex fixes the problem.

The only thing I can see is that in some articles it mentions adding something to the solr.xml file, but the solr.xml file in my setup bears no resemblance to the acticles in question.

Answer (score 2):

The SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex constructor has only 4 parameters.

You need to comment the following `<param desc="group">experience</param>` from the **Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Analytics.config**.

In order to know if the `sitecore_analytics_index` is taking 4 parameters, check it via the /sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx since you are patching up the `sitecore_analytics_index`

You can also check the following link: [Switch Solr Index](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/search_and_indexing/indexing/switch_solr_indexes)

Thanks

Comment: No dice. I can decompile and see that it does indeed only take 4 params, and checked that there are only four params for each index. But I still get the error